# Javascript promise.all()

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I have this piece of code.

```
function a() {
  var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
  var promise2 = 42;
  var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'foo');
  });

  Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
    console.log("done", values);
  });
}

async function b() {
 await a(); 
}

b();
console.log("here")
```

Here, we get the output

> "here"

and then after two seconds, we get

> "done" Array [3, 42, "foo"]

How do I change this code so that inside function b(), we are actually waiting for a() to complete and then continue the execution of the code?

Hence, the output I want is

Wait two seconds and see

> "done" Array [3, 42, "foo"]
>
> "here"

Comment: Since `a` doesn't return anything, there's nothing to wait for - and you'll also need to await `b`

Comment: on top of what @chrispbacon said, i can tell you that even if function `a` did in fact return a promise, function `b` would be waiting for it yes, however the `console.log("here")` wouldn't wait for function `b` to finish, you should do something like `b().then(()=>console.log("here"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the above code like this:

```
function a() {
    var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
    var promise2 = 42;
    var promise3 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'foo');
    });

    // Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function (values) {
    //     console.log("done", values);
    // });

    return Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
}

async function b() {
    let values = await a();
    console.log('done', values);
    // return values; // This will get automatically get wrapped into a promise.
    return Promise.resolve(values);
}

b().then(() => { console.log("here") });
```

Here `a` returns a promise and after that `b` also returns a promise which is immediately resolved.

Comment: why `return Promise.resolve(values);` not `return values`?

Comment: async functions returns an asyncFunction object....
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

So, when you return values from it, it will actually return an object with 'pending' state (basically a promise). Therefore we have to get the values by using then.

Comment: when did I ask about `.then`?

Comment: async functions returns a promise, and if promise is not returned then it gets automatically wrapped in a promise. So, yes, we can just write return values instead of returning a promise. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in more than one way.

**Form 1**

First, because `a` doesn't return, as stated by @chris-p-bacon, instead of handling the Promise itself, you can return it.

Instead of

```js
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log("done", values);
});
```

use

```js
return Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
```

**Form 2**

The other way is to make the `a` function an `async function`, and then await for the Promise.all, this way:

```js
async function a() {
  ...

  await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
}
```

In this second form, different than the first form, you can still handle the Promise after it returns:

```js
async function a() {
  ...

  var values = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
  console.log("done", values);
}
```

**Conclusion**

Both forms answer your request to *change* your piece of code, and it will be almost equivalent to your code. But notice that if you were using the `catch` function you would have to use a try-catch instead, around the `await`.

Answer (score 1):

`b` is the async function. So either you can put await front while calling it then execute rest or do the .then like

```
b().then(res => {
 //rest codes  
 console.log("here")
})
```

By the way that is not required to put await in front of `promise2` as thats not even a promise object.

Answer (score 1):

Your promise always runs asynchronously so that you have to wait until it get resolved and then you can print your "**here**" console.

```js
function a() {
  var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
  var promise2 = 42;
  var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'foo');
  });

  return Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
   return values;
  });
}

 function b() {
 a().then( function(res) {
  console.log("done", res);
  console.log("here")
 })
}

b();
```