# Perform two functions simultaneously

Tags: javascript

I have a function that refreshes the data of my component when the function is called. At this moment it only works for one component at a time. But I want to refresh two components at once. This is my refresh function:

```
   fetchDataByName = name => {
        const { retrievedData } = this.state;
        const { fetcher } = this.props;
        const fetch = _.find(fetcher, { name });

        if (typeof fetch === "undefined") {
          throw new Error(`Fetch with ${name} cannot be found in fetcher`);
        }

        this.fetchData(fetch, (error, data) => {
          retrievedData[name] = data;
          this._isMounted && this.setState({ retrievedData });
        });
      };
```

My function is called like this:

```
refresh("meetingTypes");
```

As it it passed as props to my component:

```
return (
        <Component
          {...retrievedData}
          {...componentProps}
          refresh={this.fetchDataByName}
        />
      );
```

I tried passing multiple component names as an array like this:

```
const args = ['meetingTypes', 'exampleMeetingTypes'];
refresh(args);
```

And then check in my `fetchDataByName` function if `name` is an array and loop through the array to fetch the data. But then the function is still executed after each other instead of at the same time. So my question is:

> What would be the best way to implement this that it seems like the
>   function is executed at once instead of first refreshing meetingTypes
>   and then exampleMeetingTypes?

Should I use `async/await` or are there better options?

The `fetchData` function:

```
fetchData = (fetch, callback) => {
    const { componentProps } = this.props;
    let { route, params = [] } = fetch;
    let fetchData = true;

    // if fetcher url contains params and the param can be found
    // in the component props, they should be replaced.
    _.each(params, param => {
      if (componentProps[param]) {
        route = route.replace(`:${param}`, componentProps[param]);
      } else {
        fetchData = false; // don't fetch data for this entry as the params are not given
      }
    });

    if (fetchData) {
      axios
        .get(route)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          if (this.isMounted) {
            callback(null, data);
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.response.status == 403) {
            this._isMounted && this.setState({ errorCode: 403 });
            setMessage({
              text: "Unauthorized",
              type: "error"
            });
          }

          if (error.response.status == 401) {
            this._isMounted && this.setState({ errorCode: 401 });
            window.location.href = "/login";
          }

          if (error.response.status != 403) {
            console.error("Your backend is failing.", error);
          }
          callback(error, null);
        });
    } else {
      callback(null, null);
    }
  };
```

Comment: For doing something asynchronously, you can use `async/await` or `Promise`

Comment: @PrerakSola - It's very likely that `fetchData` above is async (old-style async, uses a callback).

Comment: Intrinsically, calling async functions will not block anyway,. With the code provided I do not see anything that would serialise, unless fetchData is sync..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah I see. I did not see the callback. I

Comment: use promise or async/await. Wait for all data resolved and then set data: exapmple answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321708/javascript-promise-all/58322023#58322023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `fetchData` works asynchronously (ajax or similar). To refresh two aspects of the data in parallel, simply make two calls instead of one:

```
refresh("meetingTypes");
refresh("exampleMeetingTypes");
```

The two ajax calls or whatever will run in parallel, each updating the component when it finishes. **But**: See the "Side Note" below, there's a problem with `fetchDataByName`.

If you want to avoid updating the component twice, you'll have to update `fetchDataByName` to either accept multiple names or to return a promise of the result (or similar) rather than updating the component directly, so the caller can do multiple calls and wait for both results before doing the update.

---

Side note: This aspect of `fetchDataByName` looks suspect:

```
fetchDataByName = name => {
  const { retrievedData } = this.state;  // <=============================
  const { fetcher } = this.props;
  const fetch = _.find(fetcher, { name });

  if (typeof fetch === "undefined") {
    throw new Error(`Fetch with ${name} cannot be found in fetcher`);
  }

  this.fetchData(fetch, (error, data) => {
    retrievedData[name] = data;          // <=============================
    this._isMounted && this.setState({ retrievedData });
  });
};
```

Two problems with that:

1. It updates an object stored in your state **directly**, which is something you must never do with React.
2. It replaces the entire `retrievedData` object with one that may well be stale.

Instead:

```
fetchDataByName = name => {
  // *** No `retrievedData` here
  const { fetcher } = this.props;
  const fetch = _.find(fetcher, { name });

  if (typeof fetch === "undefined") {
    throw new Error(`Fetch with ${name} cannot be found in fetcher`);
  }

  this.fetchData(fetch, (error, data) => {
    if (this._isMounted) {                                  // ***
      this.setState(({retrievedData}) => (                  // ***
        { retrievedData: {...retrievedData, [name]: data} } // ***
      );                                                    // ***
    }                                                       // ***
  });
};
```

That removes the in-place mutation of the object with spread, and uses an up-to-date version of `retrievedData` by using the callback version of `setState`.

Comment: I already tried this, but then the components get refreshed after each other instead of at the same time

Comment: I added the `fetchData` function to my question

Comment: @Baspa like TJ said, in that case alter your function to pass an array, use promise.all before calling your setState.  ps. If you don't want to use promises, you can do this using just the callbacks, but it's not as nice.. :)

Comment: @Baspa - After posting my answer, I saw a problem with `fetchDataByName` (two, in fact), so I've called those out above.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem with setting the state. @T.J.Crowder So the best way should be to use `promise.all` on `this.fetchData`? @Keith

Comment: @Baspa - That would be reasonable. Make `fetchData` return a promise instead of accepting a callback, and don't have it update state directly. (FWIW, I'd make it reject on error rather than handling errors inline.) Then `Promise.all([fetchData("a"), fetchData("b")]).then(([aresult, bresult]) => {/*...set state...*/}).catch(error => {/*...handle errors...*/});` but that does mean that a failure to get `a` will prevent showing `b`, so you might use [`allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) instead and weed out the errors.